# Join multiple List(Of String) in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, string, linq, list, join

I need to join these three `List(Of String)`:

```
Dim lst1 As New List(Of String) From {"man1"}
Dim lst2 As New List(Of String) From {"/1child", "/2child"}
Dim lst3 As New List(Of String) From {"/1age", "/2age"}
```

To get output like this `List(Of String)`:

```
man1/1child/1age
man1/1child/2age
man1/2child/1age
man1/2child/2age
```

What is most effictive way? LINQ way? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, can't remember the VB syntax at the moment, but I believe this should work: `lst1.SelectMany(m => lst2.SelectMany(c => lst.Select(a => m + c + a)))`

Comment: It works, thanks! Post the answer and I'll accept it! VB.NET version: `Dim result = lst1.SelectMany(Function(m) lst2.SelectMany(Function(c) lst3.[Select](Function(a) m + c + a))).ToList`

Comment: @Asad `lst1.SelectMany(function(l) lst2.SelectMany(function(ls) lst3.Select(function(lst) string.format("{0}{1}{2}",l,ls,lst))))`

Comment: @ValeO Since you've got the exact answer figured out, you can post this as an answer to your own question (which is encouraged).

Comment: @asawyer, your variant works well too, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of these variants works:

```
Dim result = lst1.SelectMany(Function(m) lst2.SelectMany( _ 
Function(c) lst3.[Select](Function(a) m + c + a))).ToList

Dim result2 = lst1.SelectMany(Function(l) lst2.SelectMany( _ 
Function(ls) lst3.Select(Function(lst) String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", l, ls, lst))))
```